# A sectioning scheme for a book with Memoir Class

Tags: sectioning, memoir, book-class

I wrote a book with the DTP Adobe Frame Maker and I, myself, did the paragraph formatting and page layout. Now, I am translating the book to English and, this time, the book is being formatted and written with LaTeX. But formatting paragraphs and creating page layout in LaTeX is not a trivial task.
I attached a TOC scheme of the Frame Maker book. The scheme has five levels. But, the last depth, corresponding to the Subsubsubsection, is not numbered. I think a number for such a subsection is a big one—with many digits—and, aesthetically is inelegant! Instead, such subsection begins with a Dingbat symbol, that has the Unicode U+00E3 code.

I need help to create this sectioning scheme for a Memoir Class. Any help is appreciated!

[image: TOC_Scheme]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: that arrow head may have position hex E3 in some legacy sysmbol font that you have not mentioned but it is not Unicode U+00E3 which is ã

Comment: @Carlisle I said the arrow head is from the font Adobe Type 1 Dingbat. There is a package of this font as follows https://ctan.org/pkg/dingbat?lang=en.

Comment: @Mensch Excuse me, I do not have an issue. I do not know how to start the sectioning scheme yet--I am a newbie. But what I want is like what is in the photo.